# Webservice into array , substring suitable?

Tags: java, substring

I am currently developing an Java app in Android Studio.

I am facing a little problem. I have a big file from a web-service, and it's already in a variable. At the end I would like to have an array for each `SKU` (*always under a style*). And the array should only contain the first `9` values. So array one should be named: `sku1[9]` with

```
sku1[0]="123456"
sku1[1]="123456"
sku1[2]="123456"
...
```

Then I need another array: `sku2[9]` with

```
sku2[0]="123456"
sku2[1]="123456"
sku2[2]="123456"
...
```

Any ideas how to extract the needed strings from this big ass file and put them into a nice array?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You need to be more specific... Is the entire big file already in a variable loaded into the memory or it's in the file:  the question is confusing: *"big file"* , *"it's already in a variable"*, *"extract the needed strings from this big ass file"*.

Answer (score 0):

As the String is already into a variable, you can use `Pattern` matching to extract the `sku` Strings, e.g.:

```
String s = "<!DOCTYPE> <div>    styles = {\"sku1_1\":\"12\",..}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\"sku[0-9]_[0-9]\":\"[0-9]+\")");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This will by default ignore the Strings that have more than one digit after `_`.

**Update**

If you want the values to be stored inside an `array` then you can declare an `arraylist`, add the elements into it and convert it back to `array`, e.g.:

```
String s = "<!DOCTYPE> <div>    styles = {\"sku1_1\":\"12\",..}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\"sku[0-9]_[0-9]+\":\"[0-9]\")");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()){
   String[] tokens = m.group(1).split(":");
   values.add(tokens[1]);
}
String[] array = values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
```

This way, it will put the values inside an array. If you want multiple arrays then you can check the value of the first token (i.e. `tokens[0]`) and initialise the new list if it has changed from let's say `sku1` to `sku2`.

Comment: Are you suggesting to read the entire *"big file"*  into a `String` in the memory?!

Comment: `it's already in a variable` this is what the question says. I am not suggesting anything on how to read the file, the above pattern works for each line as well.

Comment: You're right, the question is confusing: *"big file"* , *"it's already in a variable"*, *"extract the needed strings from this big ass file"*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to store it in an array as described above? I just get the String output now with your solution. Thanks for your help!